# styling Yuri Kanivets' WheelView

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been playing with Yuri Kanivet's WheelView  ( http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) , a nice iPhone like wheel control, and I must say I like it.  However, I would like to style the wheel items - smaller text, and add lines betweeen the items, but there aren't any styling methods on the control.

I'm instantiating the control in code.  I've tried calling setTheme() and passing a custom theme in the activity's onCreate() method, but it doesn't have any affect on the wheel items.  Any ideas on how I could style the control programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the textsize of the wheelview, you can change the DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE value of AbstractWheelTextAdapter.java, that's used in the configureTextView method.
As for the gab between the lines, you can set the paddding of a single view, like convertView.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10); in the "getItem" method, also in AbstractWheelTextAdapter.java

hope that can help you.